# Issues with SureFire Booter

Tags: maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

Recently I can observe very weird behavior of TestNG tests launched from surefire plugin. Once suite is finished tests execution just hang without any exceptions or informations. After killing executtion and clearing workspace it seems that SurefireBotter hanged:

```
    Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\[path]\target\surefire\surefirebooter380043352616947373.jar
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\[path]\target\surefire\surefirebooter380043352616947373.jar
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute(CleanMojo.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete C:\[path]\target\surefire\surefirebooter380043352616947373.jar
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:249)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:158)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:158)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute(CleanMojo.java:193)
```

The curious thing is that after killing process with maven manually after it hangs, I still can see java processes in system responsible for that booter.

Framework that I'm using is based on Spring, however I have no idea if this is meaningfull :)

Any hints will be more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the java process using JPS (a tool provide with the JDK). JPS will list process and id. You can kill the process by the id